# Excel: Finding items in a column in another column and deleting them

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm trying to use the following names (Nancy, Daniel, Sergio, Patty) that are listed on the right-side column (column H) finding them on Table that is on the left-side and deleting them (along its whole row).

[image]

Here's how the final table would look like with the deleted rows:

[image]

Could this be done with a simple VLOOKUP formula?

Comment: To delete you need `VBA` coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete rows using formula. For doing that you would need VBA code. But with `FILTER` formula you could crate new table excluding list in `H`:

```
=FILTER(A1:C7,ISNA(MATCH(A1:A7,H2:H4,0)))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, how about filtering for Name2,Name4,Name6 rows in the Table, and then, I'll just manually delete them?

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with just hiding the rows which contains a name in the list:

1. Format the current data as table (should be <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
2. Add column 'Hide' to the table.
3. Add this formula in the 'Hide' column: `COUNTIF(H2:H5, A2)`
4. Make sure the formula is correctly defined for the entire column.
5. You should have only '1's and '0's in this column. Filter it to show only '0' and you are done.
6. Or you can filter to show only the '1's and delete them if you wish that.